# What happens to Will Turner's heart?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-men-tell-no-tales

#### Warning: Spoilers for *At World's End* and *Dead Men Tell No Tales*.

Davy Jones put a curse on his heart, making sure that anyone who destroys the heart must remove their own heart, and preferably keep in in a box.  Now, with the destruction of the Trident in Dead Men Tell No Tales, all the curses are lifted, and Will Turner sails up to the shore on the Dutchman, where an elated Elizabeth (the keeper of Will's heart) meets him and they make out.  Seems good.

Except she's got his heart in a box - a heart that, judging by the big scar on Will's chest, was removed by relatively non-magical means.  And un-cursed people tend to be in trouble when they are on a ship and their heart is in a box on land.  So, what's the deal with Will's curse?  Did his physically removed heart find a more magical way of making its way back in?  Was the heart brought to him really fast by someone right after the Trident was destroyed?  Does un-cursing accommodate to living with your heart outside your body? Is this ever addressed by the makers of the movies?

Answer (score 2):

### It is assumed to be back inside him

As you note:

> Davy Jones put a curse on his heart, making sure that anyone who destroys the heart must remove their own heart, and preferably keep in in a box.

So once the curse was lifted, there is no reason for Will to keep his heart in a box.

[BlueMoon93 summarizes this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/74116/43753) for us on [movies.se]

> Once the trident was broken, the curse was broken. He
>
> - was able to come back to land
> - lost the barnacles and sea-elements covering his body
> - has his heart beating back inside him (otherwise he would just die)
> - no longer commands the Flying Dutchman
> - no longer survives underwater
>
> Despite this not being directly showed in the movie, it seems like a reasonable interpretation. He is just a regular man now, and doesn't have a hollow chest (as he is no longer cursed).

As a final note, keep in mind that POTC likes to play fast and loose with continuity (*cough* dead men tell no tales *cough*), so the heart is going to be exactly where Disney needs it to be next time they need it, regardless of whether or not it contradicts earlier fact.

Comment: So is the idea that the heart teleported into his chest?  It didn't teleport out of there.

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/GxRJqOTR2vv0Y/giphy.gif

Comment: In all seriousness, it's a magical world. It's a safe bet his heart was magically reinstated.

Comment: I would imagine so :)  Although I find the answer *it's magic* to be generally unsatisfactory to fantasy-related consistency questions.  Fantasy often involves a magical world, but generally functions under a set of rules we can figure out.  And, even in the world of PotC, non-cursed people tend to die really quickly when their heart isn't pumping their blood.  If the only answer is that it's a magical world and magic happens, I'd say that's a plot hole.  Not an especially troubling plot hole, but a plot hole nonetheless.

Comment: Thats fair. Unfortunately with POTC, what is canon today might not be canon tomorrow, so it becomes very difficult to rationalize some of the things it does.

Comment: There are alternatives to the heart literally teleporting from the box (chest) into his chest. For example, the magic could have simultaneously caused a new heart to grow in his chest (because magic) and start pumping blood like before, and destroyed the old unlinked heart. Achieves a similar purpose without the messy timey wimey space nonsense.

Comment: @DariM That's true. When it comes to fantasy and magic, it's all possible.  And what legitimizes it isn't so much an explanation of the event, but rather a simple description.  Describe it, and it's a legit part of the world.  If there is no description, the assumption is that the event makes some logical sense, right?  In this case, I get that magic etc., but why would an un-cursing result in a new heart being grown?  After all, it wasn't the curse that removed the heart.  It was a guy with a knife.  So I've trouble seeing an implied story structure that non-surgically restores it, you know?